# Auto Layout proportionally Scaling Views

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, interface-builder, autolayout

I have already found several questions and answers about this topic but I simply cannot get this to work for me.

[image: Scaling]

The blue rectangle is a UIView which contains the Test Label and Gear image button. The red one is a second UIView.

What I'd like to do is to get the blue bar (which is a UIView) increase in size for larger sized screens, which will result in the scaling of the Label and settings button, while the Red UIView shrink in height so the blue UIView can become larger. So basically the question is, how to proportionally scale the UIViews for different screen sizes.

I have tried using aspect ratio constraints, height constraints (greater than/less than) but I just can't get the desired effect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try proportional height and width. You need to make constraints for Equal Heights and/or equal Widths and then you double click on the constraint and change the multiplier for example 0.2 if you wish to make First Item to be 20% of second item in width and 2.0 for 200% (means double) in width. to make it increase or decrease proportionally according to your requirement[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works pretty well. Now I'm stuck with Label scaling and fonts. This is a nightmare...

Comment: for scaling label and fonts check my answer, you should use size-classes: with this feature you can also set font size for one size-class for example, I'm updating my answer for this.

Comment: you normally use fixed font sizes for labels and dont give them height and width but set their trailing, leading, top, bottom constraints. but if you want the font size to shrink when view is compressed then you can give autoshrink value to "minimum font scale" or "minimum font size". and yes you can use size classes as Massimo suggest :) but Size classes may not be supported completely by IOS 7. However you can set fonts for for different size classes i.e. iphones portrait, iphones landscape, ipad portrait, and ipad landscape for all types of resolutions.

Comment: @AsadullahAli i am using visual studio for storyboard and can't set multiplier less then zero. any other way of doing it ?

Comment: @BasitZIa Sorry not sure about the storyboard on Visual studio though you can open storyboard file in a textEditor and find the constraint by id and change it's value

Comment: @BasitZIa - what are you trying to do?  The only meaningful multipliers are positive numbers: less than 1 (e.g. 0.5) makes first item smaller than second item; greater than 1 makes first item larger.   And, if multiplier not doing what you expect, have you tried swapping the first and second items (the dropdown has "swap .." as one choice)?  Or if "nothing is happening", then it can't compute a solution - either need to add some other constraint or have conflicting constraints.

Answer (score 9):

You have two ways for do that:

### **1. Proportional constraints:**

but if you set a proportional height for one view means that the view change for every little change in screen size. For example, your view can be a little bigger switching from 4" to 4,7", but does not mean that it is a bad idea.

For use that feature just [check the answer by Asadullah Ali :)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29562197/4582941)

### **2. Use size-classes:**

if you using Xcode 6 you can use the size classes and add a constraints just for a screen size; it's not difficult to use, check the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/AboutAdaptiveSizeDesign.html).

For this feature you need to able size classes for your Storyboard:

[image]

after that you can set up your view controller like you want and add a rule just for one of the classes:

[image]

you can tell to Xcode "ok, if the screen size is an 5,5 at least use this rule".

Remember that for add a constraint for a specific size classes you need first select the size class then add normally your constraint: when a size class is selected (you can check in the size classes control) Xcode add the constraints just for that class.

**EDIT 1**: If you have some trouble with **scaling font** & similar you can also use size-classes feature just for **scaling a font size in a label** for example; you find this option by clicking on this after activated the size classes feature:

[image: How add a font size for one size class]

---

I prefer tell you everything I know about your problem but in your case personally I would use the **first solution**: your view can dynamically change whatever is the screen size.

You need just find the best proportional percentage: you can set maybe around 10%, so the **0.1 multiplier with first item your blue view and for second item the red view**.

Comment: The question is about scaling Views. Resizing fonts should go in a different post.

Comment: Did you read the entire answer? Resizing fonts it's just the last point