# How to set UILabel font size in iOS in terms of dp's (Not in points) just like android with only autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, autolayout

In my iOS program, I want to set UILabel size in dp's. So that when the iOS device changes, according to scale factor (@1x, @2x, or @3x) my UILabel size will also changes proportionally.

Lets say for eg. @1x scale factor, I have UILabel size = 15pt, then It will automatically become 30pt @2x and 45pt @3x

Comment: You can use proportional width constraint  with superview , with that you can achieve behaviour which you are looking for

Comment: @bhumit - can you please tell me in more details. Because I am very beginer to autolayout so that I can try it. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562015/auto-layout-proportionally-scaling-views/29562197#29562197 You can go through this answer, if you set multiplier 0.3 that will make sure width of label will be 30% of width to view.

Comment: Thanks bhumit. I just have small doubt. What if I have to change the font size of UILabel also proportional to width of device i.e. [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ] . size . width

Comment: I am not entirely sure about that but this ans might help . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4865458/dynamically-changing-font-size-of-uilabel/21382185#21382185

Comment: Its ok Bhumit. Thanks for the help. You almost help me out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether you can  set UILabel size in dp's but instead what you can do is set "Autoshink" to "Minimum Font Size" and provide minimum desire font.

[image: Select your label and assign Autoshrink under Label in Attribute inspector]

Comment: Thanks rokon. As per your answer I searched some more things on google. Where I came across these two properties.

@property(nonatomic) BOOL adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth
@property(nonatomic) BOOL adjustsLetterSpacingToFitWidth

These are UILabel properties. I also found minimumFontSize is deprecated in iOS 6. I also found similar kind of article at http://petestabletpage.blogspot.in/2014/10/how-to-make-ios-label-grow-automatically.html

What I actually want is depending on width of my device my UILabel font size I want to automatically change. Are these helpful?

Comment: Yes, Depending on your device screen font will change but will not go over font size you assign and below minimum font size.

Comment: You are most welcome. If my ans helps you to solve your problem please give me a vote.